# Given $x^y=e^{x-y}$, find $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$.

Tags: derivatives

[image]
I have done the sum by taking log but not getting my final answer right. Please help me

Comment: Why do you believe that answer is incorrect?  Keep in mind that, because of the known relation between $x$ and $y$, there are likely to be many equivalent ways to write the solution.  Also, you should simplify your fraction.

Answer (score 1):

> Given $x^y=e^{x-y}$, find $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$.

\begin{align}
x^y&=e^{x-y}\\
\ln (x^y)&=x-y\\
y\ln x&=x-y\\
\frac{d}{dx}(y\ln x)&=\frac{d}{dx}(x-y)\\
\frac{dy}{dx}\ln x+\frac{y}{x}&=1-\frac{dy}{dx}\\
(1+\ln x)\frac{dy}{dx}&=1-\frac{y}{x}\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{1-\frac{y}{x}}{1+\ln x}\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\boxed{\frac{x-y}{x+x\ln x}}
\end{align}

---

Edit to match provided answer:
\begin{align}
x^y&=e^{x-y}\\
\log (x^y)&=x-y\\
y\log x&=x-y\\
y+y\log x&=x\\
y(1+\log x)&=x\\
y&=\frac{x}{1+\log x}\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{(1+\log x)-x(\frac1x)}{(1+\log x)^2}\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\boxed{\frac{\log x}{(1+\log x)^2}}
\end{align}

Comment: Actually the correct answer is given as log x/(1+log x) ²

Comment: @KalpitPrabhu compare now.

Comment: For the future, you may be able to get the most appropriate answer by outlining the topic at hand (obviously from the above, you can see that the derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$ can be achieved by both differentiating an explicit function $y$ in terms of $x$ _OR_ by implicit differentiation).

Answer (score 0):

It is $$y\ln(x)=x-y$$ differentiating with respect to $x$ we get
$$y'\ln(x)+\frac{y}{x}=1-y'$$ so we obtain
$$y'(\ln(x)+1)=\frac{x-y}{x}$$ or $$y'=\frac{x-y}{x(\ln(x)+1)}$$

Comment: Actually the correct answer is given as log x/(1+log x) ²